# Find out whether active celery tasks have been retried or not - how?

Tags: celery, celery-3, celery-4

I am looking for ways to find out which of the currently active tasks have been retried and how many times (if possible).

This is basically an extension to what `celery inspect active` does. Ideally I would like to generate a report in the following format:

```
Task ID                                Retried  No-retries
--------------------------------------------------------------------
'b81ed28d-03a8-4e6b-849f-1135f1717fc5' Yes      3
'26cb2668-ba0d-41f5-b50c-45ce4802adf4' No       0
'93ef6b55-0729-4a02-9d14-aff5c1ff0c54' Yes      2
```

Is this information available anywhere?
I use Redis both as broker and result backend.